# Find position vector and parallel vector from symmetric vector line equation

Tags: vectors

I'm struggling with this problem:

> Find the position vector a of a point on the line described by the equation that follows, and
>   also find a vector b parallel to the line 
>   $$\frac{x + 1}3 = \frac{y + 4}{-3} = \frac z2$$

Comment: Can you think of values of $(x,y,z)$ such that the statement above is true.  How about making each term equal to $0?$ That will give you a point on the line.  Now make each term equal to 1.  That will give you a second point.  The difference between the two points will give you a direction.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. question will be more likely to be answer if you add your thought and what you tried in the question. Also, in MSE you can use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference . this time I added it, next time you should use it

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From

$$\frac{x + 1}3 = \frac{y + 4}{-3} = \frac z2$$

let $x=t\in \mathbb{R}$ and obtain the **parametric equation** for the line

$$x=t\implies y=-t-5 \quad z=\frac23(t+1)$$

thus the **position vector** is

$$P=\left(t,-t-5,\frac23(t+1)\right)=\left(0,-5,\frac23\right)+t\left(1,-1,\frac23\right)$$

thus a **parallel vector** is

$$b=\left(1,-1,\frac23\right)$$